# Vertical scroll bar with Ionic multiple views

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, scrollbar

I'm using multiple named views to build an Ionic app screen.

The problem is, I have a vertical scroll bar that spans the entire screen, even though there is no scrollable content.

The scroll bar covers the header, content and footer sections.
The content section contains a list, so I'd like a scroll bar for that section, but only if there is enough content to need one.

Here is the code.....

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->
    <!--For users deploying their apps to Windows 8.1 or Android Gingerbread, platformOverrided.js
    will inject platform-specific code from the /merges folder -->
    <script src="js/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
      <div ui-view="header"></div>
      <div ui-view="content"></div>
      <div ui-view="footer"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
        <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
  </ion-content>
```

content.html

```
  <ion-content class="has-header has-footer">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="playlist in playlists" href="#/app/playlists/{{playlist.id}}">
        {{playlist.title}}
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
```

footer.html

```
  <ion-content>
      <ion-footer-bar align-title="left" class="bar-royal">
          <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button">Left Button</button>
          </div>
          <h1 class="title">Footer</h1>
          <div class="buttons">
              <button class="button">Right Button</button>
          </div>
      </ion-footer-bar>
  </ion-content>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
      if (cordova.platformId === "ios" && window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
            'header': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/header.html'
            },
            'content': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/content.html',
                controller: 'contentCtrl'
            },
            'footer': {
                templateUrl: '/templates/footer.html'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('contentCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.playlists = [
      { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
      { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
      { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
      { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
      { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
      { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 }
    ];
});
```

Do you know how I can remove the full screen scroll bar, but keep one for the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

As u can see there is a scrollbar inside content area. Header and footer are sticky. Can u provide some screenshots ?

Comment: I've only tested on ripple emulator at the moment which is where I saw the scroll bar. I'll have a look on my Android device - sorry if I've wasted your time! I'll update when I get home. Thanks

Comment: btw also try to put overflow-scroll="true" inside content.html

Comment: You're right - it looks fine on the device. Thanks for your help!